# Can we extend convex combination to integral?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, inequality, convex-analysis, jensen-inequality

The definition of the convex combination is given as:
$$x=\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2,\forall \lambda \in [0,1]$$
It can be obviously extend to multi-terms form as:
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i x_i,\sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i=1,\lambda_i \ge 0$$
I wonder can we extend it to a continous form as:
$$x=\int xp(x)dx,\int p(x)=1,p(x)\ge 0$$
If we can get the contious version. We can then prove the probability inequality:
$$f(E_p[x])\le E_p[f(x)]$$

Answer (score 1):

This is called [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, under appropriate conditions this works.  More generally, if $\mu$ is a probability measure on $X$ and $f$ is a $\mu$-integrable function, we can approximate $\int_X f \; d\mu$ by convex combinations $\sum_{j} f(x_j) p_j$ with $p_j \ge 0$ and $\sum_j p_j = 1$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the measure theory. Are there any hands-on resources for me to learn the basic ideas? Or can it be proved without using of measure theory?

Comment: @maple If $p$ is continuous then you can think of approximating it by simple functions and using Riemann sums.